# cannot run thinkorswim behind corporate firewall: "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: proxy, self-signed-certificate, ameritrade

In windows, when I install and run thinkorswim inside company network (with its own self-signed ssl cert), it cannot connect via https to tdameritrade's server.  How do I update tos's java runtime with the self-signed cert?

Answer (score 1):

open command prompt in windows and run the following command to install company's cacert into thinkorswim's jre:

```
cd C:\<thinkorswim-install-dir>\jre\bin\
keytool.exe -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -storepass changeit -alias mycertificate -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -file c:\mycert.cer
```

For MacOS

```
cd /Applications/thinkorswim/.install4j/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/bin
./keytool -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -storepass changeit -alias mycertificate -keystore ../lib/security/cacerts -file /path/to/mycert.cer
```